# Is it true kernel area address translations in page tables must be global translations?

Tags: x86, cpu, intel, processor

Is it true that Kernel area address translations present in a process page directory (page tables) must be global translations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the global flag is only to optimize TLB usage. The advantage of global pages is that they take only one TLB slot instead of one per process and they aren't flushed by context switches.